# FormGroup validator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-datatable

How can I add validator to formgroup that contains formcontrols.

I have this.

```
users.forEach(e => {
  console.log(e);
  this.filasValidator.push(new FormGroup({
      dia: new FormControl('0')
  },
    [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]
  ));
});
console.log(this.filasValidator.controls[0].invalid);
```

FilasValidator is a FormArray

in template html i have this

```
  <ng-template formArrayName="filas"
               #inputTemplate
               let-value="value"
               let-row="row"
               let-column="column"
               let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <label [formGroupName]="rowIndex" class="pya-cell">
      <small class="text-muted d-block d-lg-none">{{ column.name }}</small>
      <!--REVISAR VALUE, DA ERROR DE REASIGNACION -->
      <input
        (input)="editHour(rowIndex, column.prop, $event)"
        formControlName="dia"
        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': filasValidator.controls[rowIndex].invalid}"
        type="number"
        value="{{ value }}"
        class="number text-center w-50 form-control light"
      />
    </label>
  </ng-template>
```

It is difficult to explain, but look I have a table, in which there are several days of the week, to those days I must put a formcontrol, but the row must be valid if at least 1 record is greater than 0.
That is why I need the validation to be outside the formcontrols

I tried this

```
  this.filasValidator.push(new FormGroup({
      lunes: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      martes: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      miercoles: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      jueves: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      viernes: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1))
  },
    [Validators.required]
  ));
```

But i need Validators.min outside the FormControls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

I did this change, making a custom validator and putting in the FormGroup to validate all fields

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-grvr9l?file=src/app/opponent-details.component.ts)

```js
export class OpponentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
      objFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          test: [null],
          test2: [null]
        },
        { validators: [this.validatorArray()] }
      );

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {}

     validatorArray(): ValidatorFn {
        return (group: FormGroup) => {
          for (let key of Object.keys(group.controls)) {
           if (group.controls[key].value > 0) return null;
        }

        return { min: 1 }
      };
   }
}
```

Original answer:

You can put a validator in your FormGroup the same way that you put in your FormControl, like this:

```
new FormGroup({dia: new FormControl('0')}, [Validators.required])
```

Comment: Hi your code is the same that i wrote. I have a validator in form group. The issue is that the .invalid does not work for me, for dia formControl. For example if i had dia1 and dia2 formcontrol, i want share the form group validator in these two formcontrols, and validate this with ngClass in template.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Did you try with it: this.filasValidator.at(0).invalid?

Comment: It is difficult to explain, but look I have a table, in which there are several days of the week, to those days I must put a formcontrol, but the row must be valid if at least 1 record is greater than 0.
That is why I need the validation to be outside the formcontrols

Comment: You can make a custom validator (where you put Validators.required) put this validator that you created. So, this validator will run into the array verifying if the value is greater than 0. If you want I can do it, but I'll just able at night (2 hours after now)

Comment: I would appreciate it, so where are the validators.required can you not put the validations that angular brings?

Comment: I need create custom validate in this syntax. `this.filasValidator.push(new FormGroup({
      lunes: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      martes: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      miercoles: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      jueves: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1)),
      viernes: new FormControl('0', Validators.min(1))
  },
    [Validators.required]
  ));` I need put validators.min outside the form controls, Greetings

Comment: I did it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jujswm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fopponent-details.component.ts

Comment: Hi, this it works but i I need that if one of the formcontrols is greater than one, the entire formgroup is valid.

Comment: I changed a little the code (edited): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rjruyp?file=src/app/opponent-details.component.ts

Comment: Wow it works! thank you, can you explain return null?

Comment: When you pass something in return (return {min: 1}), you are saying to FormGroup that it's invalid. When you pass nothing (return null), you're saying that it's valid