# Manually set validation on form

Tags: angular, forms

I have the following problem:

I have a form with several fields. I use the function below to add more form fields to the form.

It checks if the minimum number of filled form fields are present and have input. If this is the case, the submit button is activated.

However, the submit button is disabled if the form is not valid.

My question is how can I manually set the form to be valid?

```
 addFormFieldsWithInput(fields: string[]): void {
   let controlArray=[];
    const groupObj = {};
        
           
            for (let i = 0; (i < fields.length); i++) {

            controlArray.push((this.feedbackInviteForm.get(type) as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.control(fields[i])));
                this.formFieldsLength++;     
                groupObj = this.formBuilder.array(controlArray);        
                    
            }
            
            if(fields.length>=this.minFormFieldsLength){
                this.form = this.formBuilder.group(groupObj)
               
            }   
                        
            
        }
```

With this implementation the button will be disabled and it adds the right amount of form fields but there is no input and the form fields are empty.

Answer (score 0):

> It checks if the minimum number of filled form fields are present and have input. If this is the case, the submit button is activated

Put that logic in a group validator, then.
Here's an example:
[FormGroup validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67390171/formgroup-validator)

Comment: Can you please explain it further?